# How to show the newsletter with user name option in footer

Tags: magento-1.9

Can anyone suggest me how to show the newsletter with username option in the footer? Please check the reference site: http://www.oculosshop.com.br/.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple module for it or you can try any module available [here](https://github.com/aligent/newsletter-extended).

I could have provided instructions to create the module but since there are free modules available, I thought that reinventing the wheel is not a good advice.

Please check any of the above and hit like if it helped you.

Comment: can i modify my theme newsletter module and put your code that given by u or I create module different module

Comment: you remove your code ,sir

Comment: While answering and putting my code, I checked and found that there are already free modules available. That's why I removed code and shared free modules' links.

Comment: You can get the code from any of the above module links and make changes in your Magento according to that. You don't need to install these module if you want to make changes in your installation.

Comment: Did it work for you @Monukumar??

Comment: sir I have one problem I want to open the seachbar on click on searchbutton can you suggest me

Comment: Maybe your comment is not related to the current question. Please ask it as a separate question.

Comment: sir when i open the link to download there is no link to download to this module check the url          https://www.magecloud.net/marketplace/extension/add-name-field-with-newsletter/

Comment: Sorry, my bad..
Magecloud link is useful only when we have setup website in their server.

Comment: Please use https://github.com/aligent/newsletter-extended

Comment: not working sir when I call it in footer like

Comment: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mediarocks/newsletterextended')
    ->setTemplate('mediarocks/newsletterextended/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml();?>

Comment: show blank output and  i not found the layout file of its

Comment: Try <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template') ->setTemplate('mediarocks/newsletterextended/subscribe.phtml‌​')->toHtml();?> instead.